# Embed PowerBI with authentication error (AADSTS50076)

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, powerbi-embedded

I want to embed some PowerBI reports in my web application. I have a working code for a previous project. Now, I have a new project with a new Active Directory and new PowerBI. I created a new app in Active Directory and I have the TenantId. When I run `AcquireTokenAsync`, I receive an error.

```
public async Task<bool> CreatePowerBIClient()
{
    bool rtn = false;

    if (client == null)
    {
        var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(SettingsModels.Username, SettingsModels.Password);

        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsModels.AuthorityUrl);
        var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(SettingsModels.ResourceUrl, 
                                    SettingsModels.ClientId, credential);

        if (authenticationResult != null)
        {
            var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");
            client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(SettingsModels.ApiUrl), tokenCredentials);
            rtn = true;
        }
    }
    else
        rtn = true;

    return rtn;
}
```

> {"error":"interaction_required","error_description":"AADSTS50076: Due
> to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you
> moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to
> access '00000009-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.\r\nTrace ID:
> 4d6fa156-0435-4c92-9746-b0e3d6bcdb00\r\nCorrelation ID:
> 0febdcc8-cd86-46e2-a7a5-0ec0705732bb\r\nTimestamp: 2020-09-17
> 12:20:40Z","error_codes":[50076],"timestamp":"2020-09-17
> 12:20:40Z","trace_id":"4d6fa156-0435-4c92-9746-b0e3d6bcdb00","correlation_id":"0febdcc8-cd86-46e2-a7a5-0ec0705732bb","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50076","suberror":"basic_action","claims":"{"access_token":{"capolids":{"essential":true,"values":["8abf28b1-2a8a-440a-821c-9874593bec9c","9f5f13cb-276e-49fe-ad14-829ce71aef09"]}}}"}:
> Unknown error

[image: Error Screenshot]

I checked the permission on the application settings in Active Directory but I can't find a place to disable multi-factor authentication. I'm not the admin of this domain though.

[image: App settings in Azure]

What can I do?

### Update

I'm using the latest version of PowerBI packages and I replaced the code with the suggested code:

[image]

```
public async Task<bool> CreatePowerBIClient()
{
    bool rtn = false;

    if (client == null)
    {
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsModels.AuthorityUrl);

        var credential = new ClientCredential(SettingsModels.ClientId, SettingsModels.ClientSecret);
        var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(SettingsModels.ResourceUrl, credential);

        if (authenticationResult != null)
        {
            var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");
            client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(SettingsModels.ApiUrl), tokenCredentials);
            rtn = true;
        }
    }
    else
        rtn = true;

    return rtn;
}
```

with those values:

- authorityUrl: https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/
- resourceUrl: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api
- clientId and clientSecret from when I registered the app from PowerBI (also, I checked the ApplicationId in the Azure portal and it is the same)

Now, I got an error:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (BadRequest).
>
> [AdalServiceException: AADSTS90002: Tenant 'authorize' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID. Check with your subscription administrator.

[image]

I don't know what the problem is. I found useful this [post](https://www.puresourcecode.com/dotnet/csharp/connect-web-application-to-powerbi/).

Comment: Which power bi API are you targeting? v3?

Comment: According to the error, you have enabled MFA. So we cannot use `UserPasswordCredential` to get token. I suggest you use authorization code to get token : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/get-azuread-access-token#access-token-for-power-bi-users-user-owns-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, I understand that you are making use of a specific account to get the token to connect to the PowerBI report.

This error you are encountering indicates that you are passing credential of the account for which MFA is enabled. MFA is enabled at a user account level and not at the app level. To overcome this error you could use one of the below options :

**Option 1 :**

You could try seek & exemption for MFA for the account that you re using to connect to the report. Alternatively, in a lot of organization as best practice  use  service accounts with least perms without MFA enabled to perform automated task. You could make use of one of these accounts to connect to reports by granting them access.

This will not require any change in your code.

**Option 2 :**

You could generate a App Only Token. You are making a App to get authenticated against Azure AD and consuming the report. MFA will be completely out of the picture.

The App will need to be given permission to the workspace in which the report resides.

The below snippet of the code to get App only token

```
var credential = new ClientCredential(ApplicationId, ApplicationSecret);
authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, credential);
```

For detailed steps on how to create and grant permissions for an app, you could refer this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal).

**Note :**

This needs a setting to be enabled at PowerBI service by the PowerBI service Admin to consume reports by this method.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm facing an issue now. I updated the post.

Comment: can you pls try using the AuthorityURL as : `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantGUID>` or as `https://login.windows.net/common/`  ?

Comment: Thank you so much! I have now another issue to get the list of dashboards and reports. I have created a new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63953987/integration-with-powerbi-getdashboardsingroupasync-or-getreportsingroupasync-re